# Problem with Apple ID and associated email

Tags: ipad, email, apple-id

I recently switched my apple ID to a different email.  The problem is that I can no longer use the previous one.  The previous one is still there and won't go away.  I can't edit anything as a result.  Every 3 seconds I am bombarded with the old email/ID which I cannot use anymore.  Does anyone have an answer to syncing my current email so I can make the edits. No internet, contact and so on can't be use at all.  My iPad is literally jammed.  Shutting down and erasing things is useless because I can't use a password that recognizes the old email.
Can any one help me?

Comment: so how come you can not log in with old email + password, regardless if that email works or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinstate your original email password (the one associated with App Store, iMessage, iCloud etc.)

You cannot change primary email addresses without complications to the best of my knowledge. I'm stuck using an old hotmail address as my login ID because it was not possible to change the login info.

If you have no access to the previous email at all then you can't confirm the change in primary email address, either, so will need to call Apple (at least that was the case for Australia, USA may differ)